# How to subscribe to a column width change event in DataGrid

Tags: data-binding, avaloniaui, avalonia

I can't figure out how to subscribe to the column width change event.

Using the official documentation of avalonia v11, I tried to repeat something similar, but the event only fires 1 time, during the signing. But after 1 step the event no longer fires.

```
private void CreateBandHeaders()
    {
        var observable = _table.Columns[0].GetObservable(WidthProperty);
        var sub = observable.Subscribe(new AnonymousObserver<double>(OnNext));
    }

private void OnNext(double obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. In the visual tree, I look for the headings of the table and subscribe to their resizing.

```
private DataGridColumnHeader? GetHeaderByColumn(DataGridColumn column)
{
    var childs = MyDataGrid.GetVisualChildren();
    foreach (var item1 in childs)
    {
        if (item1 is not Border border)
        {
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var item2 in border.GetVisualChildren())
        {
            if (item2 is not Grid grid)
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var item3 in grid.GetVisualChildren())
            {
                if (item3 is not DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter dataGridColumnHeadersPresenter)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                foreach (var item4 in dataGridColumnHeadersPresenter.GetVisualChildren())
                {
                    if (item4 is DataGridColumnHeader header && header.Content == column.Header)
                    {
                        return header;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```